# Shortest path for multiple goals

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, a-star

I encountered a deliveryman problem that has the following constraints, and I would like to hear from you what existing algorithm(s) I should base on to create a new one, or hopefully just modify the existing.

> 1. A vertex graph with weighted edges of even-numbered vertices, with pairs of vertices, and each vertex has a weight of 15 - picking up and dropping off a package takes time.
> 2. A pair of vertices contains a "pickup location" and a "dropoff location", Pn and Dn.
> 3. The deliveryman could be in anywhere of the graph.
> 4. The deliveryman must go to the Pn vertex of a pair - "pickup location" - first then the Dn.
> 5. A vertex has weighted edges to all other vertices. (A deliveryman can go wherever s/he wants.)
> 6. The deliveryman must pass as many pairs within given time as possible.
> 7. There is a limit on the total travel time and travel time between each pair, must not exceed. The pair with less remaining time is given higher priority.

Comment: Do Pn and Dn have to be visited consecutively? How many pairs are there?

Comment: I remember that one of the ways to solve a graph problem was trying to resemble it to an already solved graph problem. So you can find if the problem is NP complete, trivial etc. So I might suggest, find a resembling problem and find a way to make your problem resemble it.

Comment: @phoad I don't claim to understand the problem fully yet, but every reasonable interpretation of what's been written so far would yield an NP-hard problem.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat They don't need to be visited consecutively. For example, the deliveryman can go P1-P2-D1-D2, as long as he picks up the package first and that the travel time between P1-D1 is within limit. There are indefinite pairs on the graph, the deliveryman only needs to travel through as many pairs as possible.

Comment: If deliveryman goes e.g. P1-P2-D1-D2, can he pick up both packages in P1 and P2, and then deliver them?

Comment: @Ante Yes, that's the spirit of it.